# What's the most elegant way to verify access rights on a method (C#.Net)

Tags: c#, web-services, security

I have a WebService built in WCF (C#.Net) that contains dozens of methods. On every methods, I wan't to validate if the current user has access to this particular action.

Right now, I have something like this :

```
    public MyContract MyMethod(int MyParameter)
    {
        ValidateAccess(MyCurrentIdentityInfo, ActionEnum);

        // Do stuff here...
    }
    public void MyMethod2(int MyParameter)
    {
        ValidateAccess(MyCurrentIdentityInfo, ActionEnum);

        // Do stuff here...
    }
    etc...
```

You'll notice that I call a method at the beginning to check the access rights and then, do the code I need. This code works fine, but I have to call this method on every method in my service and I don't find it pretty.

Is there a more elegant way to acheive what I'm trying to do? I tried using a custom attribute but didn't succeed.

Note that **I'm NOT trying to authenticate the user on the WebService itself**. In the exemple above, the user would be valid on the WebService. But I'd like to run a custom code to check if he can call a method that deletes a record for instance.

Comment: Mvc has secure action filters, you could look at how they are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can think to use [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://reducingcomplexity.blogspot.it/2010/02/wcf-and-aop-with-castledynamicproxy.html) to inject the validation of the operation on the logged user.

Comment: Interesting article though I don't see how I could what kind of actions I must validate in the "intercept" method. In the exemple above, I don't have access to the "ActionEnum" for instance.

Comment: @PiercingDegree can you better explain? From the proxy you can do exactly what you can from the service class.